# EPPlus charts not showing axis labels

Tags: epplus

I'm trying to create an automated report using EPPlus and running into an odd issue. It seems that any time I try to create a chart, everything works except the axis labels are missing. I've had no luck getting them back either through EPPlus or directly in Excel. I can't find anyone else with this problem and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if something else is going on.

Here's the chart code:

```
        var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");

        ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "1";
        ws.Cells["A2"].Value = "2";
        ws.Cells["A3"].Value = "3";
        ws.Cells["A4"].Value = "4";

        ws.Cells["B1"].Value = 10;
        ws.Cells["B2"].Value = 20;
        ws.Cells["B3"].Value = 30;
        ws.Cells["B4"].Value = 40;

        //Create the chart
        var chart = ws.Drawings.AddBarChart("Test", eBarChartType.ColumnStacked);
        chart.Title.Text = "Clustered Bar Graph Report";

        var series = chart.Series.Add(ExcelRange.GetAddress(1, 2, 4, 2), ExcelRange.GetAddress(1, 1, 4, 1));
        series.Header = "test";
```

And here's what I'm getting in Excel:

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyfre.png)

The axis labels are there, they're just blank. I've tried changing the text, I've tried deleting and re-adding, I've tried reselecting the data, I've tried changing the font, I've tried changing the chart type. No matter what I do they stay blank. I've even tried creating a new console app with just this code in it and I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that you need to apply a style to a chart to get some of the axes and gridlines to draw.  Try adding the following line right after "var chart =  ...."

```
chart.StyleManager.SetChartStyle(ePresetChartStyle.StackedColumnChartStyle1, ePresetChartColors.ColorfulPalette1);
```

In EPPlus v5.1.0 adding this line makes the axes magically appear.  Without it, I get no axes. I consider this unexpected behavior, and therefore a bug.  The same applies to many other chart types (e.g. XYScatterLines).

Comment: That does indeed get the charts displaying their Axis. Definitely unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The issues seems to be specific to V5+. I've tried 5.0.4 and 5.1.0 with no luck, but installing v4.5.3.3 fixes the problem.